# OpenGL ES 2.0 - how exactly does Matrix.looktAtM interact with glOrtho?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm writing my first opengl es 2.0 app and I'm confused about the purpose of Matrix.setLookAt.

I've got some code running that draws some objects with the center of my view set to 0,0 but I want to pan the view so that the center is at a different position in world coordinates e.g 5,5.

What do I need to pass to in glOrtho and setLookAt to achieve this? If I set the center of the view to 0,0 and draw lines across the viewport, that works fine. If I set the center to 0.25, 0 then the lines appear on the left as in the screendump below. Those lines should extend across the viewport.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:
Shader code:

```
private static final String vertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n"
        + "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n"
        + "attribute vec4 aColor;\n"
        + "varying vec4 vColor;\n"
        + "vec4 temp;"
        + "void main() {\n"
        + "  temp = aPosition;\n"
        + "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * temp;\n"
        + "  vColor = aColor;\n"
        + "}\n";

private static final String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;\n"
        + "varying vec4 vColor;\n"
        + "void main() {\n"
        + "  gl_FragColor = vColor;\n"
        + "}\n";
```

Effective onDraw code (this is actually spread over several places)

```
    // center of view should be at 0.25, 0. Height of view 1.0, width determined by ratio of viewport

    Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, -0.126471, 0.626471, -0.5, 0.5, -1, 7);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0.25, 0.0, -5, 0.25, 0.0, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, MVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttrib4f(aColorHandle, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);      // constant color
    lineVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, lineVertices);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, lineCount*2);
```

LineVertices is drawing lines with x:y coordinates:

Line from -0.126474:-0.250000 to 0.626474:-0.250000

Line from -0.126471:0.000000 to 0.626471:0.000000

Line from -0.126474:0.250000 to 0.626474:0.250000

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's expected behaviour.

1. The projection matrix takes a portion of space and maps it to the NDC cube. For orthographic ones, this is a just a block (no *frustum*). The block the code defines spans `[-0.126471, 0.626471][-0.5, 0.5][-1, 7]`. If it wouldn't alter the source space, the lines are drawn exactly from left to right.
2. Now consider what the `setLookAtM` does: By convention, after the modelview has been applied, the viewer is at `[0,0,0]` and looks in direction `[0,0,-1]`. The viewer is stepping aside for `0.25` in x direction (try to conceive this; it's the same as moving all lines *to the left*). If you wanted to have the lines drawn as before, the code'd have to move their x coordinates also (`+0.25`).

Read [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) for a technical explanation of `gluLookat`; it's effectively a translation followed by a rotation. Be sure to checkout OpenGL's spaces on [songho](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) or elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, I understand that setLookatM is displacing the eye position 0.25 to the left. Since the lines are centered at 0.25 in the x direction, should that not mean that the eye is still horizontally centered on the lines? That link you gave is in German, BTW - my high-school German isn't good enough for that.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out - you didn't quite pinpoint the problem, but you set me on the right track. The bit I didn't understand was that the the eye position in openGL is always at 0,0 in projection coordinates. gluLookat/setLookAtM translates and rotates the world coordinates into projection space. So my error was in the orthoM() call - I changed it to be centered on 0,0 and things now work as I expect. Using non-zero centered coordinates in the projection matrix has the effect of rotating the projection, not translating it.

Comment: Thanks, changed link to an english version. That last sentence of yours: projections _never ever_ do rotations.

Comment: Think about setting the projection so that e.g. the bottom clip plane has an Y value of 0, and the top clip plane is at 1.0. Compare that to a projection with bottom = -0.5 and top = 0.5. One is rotated about the X axis compared to the other. You can't rotate about the Z axis, which is what I think you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use look-at for orthor matrix. It's for perspective matrix

You can even don't call the Matrix.orthoM. If that, opengl world is (-1, 1) width and (-1, 1) height. if you draw line from (-0.25, 0) to (0.25, 0), it will be at the center of the screen and half width of the screen. (assuming your view port is 0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)

you only need one matrix to translate,rotate and scale and pass it to shader.

Comment: So if I don't use setLookatM() what do I put in my view matrix? Without it I can't shift the viewpoint from the origin, so e.g. if I want the viewpoint centred on 50,-40 how do I achieve that without setLookatM()?